# Zero or one trailing forward slash in my regex

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I don't understand what is wrong with my regex in my apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

When go to the url http://mysite.com/page1/, I get an error.  However, if I change the regex in my rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

The url http://mysite.com/page1/ works perfectly fine.  I thought the question mark means zero or one match of the previous pattern.  Why doesn't my question mark work as stated?

Comment: Oh, i guess the the regex is working, because i'm getting a "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression `^(.*)\/?$` would actually match *any* string — you're asking for "any string, either followed by a slash or not followed by a slash". Thus it will turn any request into an infinite rewrite loop if the slash is optional. You probably need a `RewriteCond` filtering out requests that *already* end in `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain a little more:

1. First pass rewrite /page1/ to page1.php?something
2. [L] says: "stop here and restart rewriting with new url"
3. Second pass rewrite /page1.php to page1.php.php?something
4. And so on...